# Can't open 32-bit Machinarium - can't read file type

Tags: 32-bit, file-format

I purchased machinarium and received my download links.  The 64-bit version downloaded and opened fine, but the cursor was not aligned with where I clicked.  I then checked my system settings and realized my computer is 32-bit, so I uninstalled the program and downloaded the Linux 32-bit version.

I unzipped the file and ended up with one "machinarium" file (file type is "file") in addition to  four folders titled "00", "01", "10", "11" - each containing 38-70 numbered files, some zipped and many not.

I cannot open machinarium.  My computer is asking how to read the file (with what program).  It opened the 64-bit one fine but it just wasn't possible to play with the cursor problem.

Please help me resolve this issue or I will be needing a refund.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try to open it? Did you try to run it from a terminal? Also, how do you know, that you run a 32-bit configuration? I am asking, because running a true 64-bit application on a 32-bit installation should not be possible (although the other way around can be done).

Comment: It says it doesn't know how to read the file, to look for a program to run it.  When I open my control panel to look at properties, it says 32-bit.  However, the 64-bit still opens and runs, it's just the cursor doesn't match up to where the actual click/selection occurs.  After trying on another computer (which said 64-bit in system properties) I think it might be my flash player.  I could disable flash on the other computer, and it works fine; when I try to disable it on my laptop, it freezes and I have to 'ctrl+f4' to exit.  Thanks for your comments, I think I'll try that first.

Answer (score 0):

On the website it says that they only have a 32 bit version for linux, so are you sure your downloading it for the correct os?

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: There are three links in the email they send (links are direct to download files, not to a website): Mac, Windows 64 bit and Linux 32 bit.  I run windows, which is why I downloaded the 64 version first.  I wonder if it is an issue with my flash player, which freezes when I attempt to disable it.  Will play around with this for now.